# Can a Java Object be a Prototype of an JavaScript Object in Nashorn?

Tags: java, javascript, nashorn

Is it possible to make an Java object the prototype of a JavaScript object? Like the following:

```js
var Person = Java.type("Person");
var hans = new Person();
hans.name = "Hans";

var employeeFactory = function() {
    var F = function(){};
    F.prototype = hans;
    return new F();
};

var fritz = employeeFactory();
print(fritz.name);
```

Here Person is a Java Bean. The variable hans is set as the instance of this Java class. The line hans.name = "Hans" sets the name field in the Java object as expected. But when the object fritz is created in the factory function, it doesn't get linked to the expected prototype. Is there any reason why the Java instance isn't accepted as prototype?

Comment: I'm really surprised that doesn't work.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but does Nashorn not support `Object.create`?

Comment: Interesting point. Not only does Nashorn know the Object.create function. If I use it instead of the factory, and try to create a JS-object with the Java instance as prototype, there is an error: TypeError: Person@73d4cc9e is not an Object. That's a real pitty. Would have been nice to inherit from Java beans.

Comment: That *is* a pity. I haven't read up on Nashorn much, unfortunately. I wonder what happens if you try it with Rhino.

Answer (score 4):

It might work in Rhino, because in Rhino all beans are wrapped into JS native objects before being exposed to the JS program. Nashorn OTOH doesn't create wrappers. You can, however, use Nashorn's non-standard `Object.bindProperties` that adds properties from one object to another, bound to the original object's instance as its this. That's essentially as close as you can get (well, it's pretty darn close) to a wrapper. The exact specification is:

```
Object.bindProperties(dst, src)
```

creates bound properties from all properties in `src` object, puts them into the `dst` object, and returns the `dst` object. Since the properties are bound to `src`, `dst.foo` will delegate to `src.foo` for its value. `bindProperties` has been coded specifically so that it can handle ordinary Java objects as `src`.

With that in mind, I believe that if you change the line

```
F.prototype = hans;
```

to

```
F.prototype = Object.bindProperties({}, hans);
```

you'll get what you wanted. That would work with `Object.create` too, e.g. `Object.create(Object.bindProperties({}, somePojo))`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm only interested in Nashorn though. But at least this gives me a hint of what goes "wrong" in Nashorn.